# Can't access the events inside the GridViewColumn's Content

Tags: c#, wpf

When I add an event to the `ListViewItem`,

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown" Handler="listViewItem_MouseDown" />
</Style>
```

Then add another event in the content inside the `GridViewColumn`,

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Action">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image x:Name="imgEdit"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Width="40"
                   Height="40"
                   Tag="{Binding ProductBarcode}"
                   Cursor="Hand"
                   MouseDown="img_MouseDown">
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/edit_button.png" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/edit_button_hovered.png" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Image.Style>
            </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

I can't fire the event in the `Image` control. The one that is firing is the event in the `ListViewItem`. How to access the event in the `Image` control?

Here are the events:

```
private void img_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    switch ((sender as Image).Name)
    {
        case "imgEdit":
            MessageBox.Show("EDIT");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
private void listViewItem_MouseDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ROW CLICKED");
}
```

Comment: What does "access the event" mean? What are you trying to do? Are you trying to get a reference to the Image in the listViewItem_MouseDown or what?

Comment: @mm8 I mean that when I click the image, the event fired should be from the clicked image only. What happens is that the event being fired instead is the ListViewItem's event even when I clicked on the image

Comment: This is how routed events work. PreviewMouseDown is a tunneling event. Please refer to my answer for more information.

Comment: @mm8 Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PreviewMouseDown` event of the `ListViewItem` will always be raised before the `MouseDown` event of the Image. This is how routed events work: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806(v=vs.110).aspx. `PreviewMouseDown` is a tunneling event and `MouseDown` is a bubbling event.

If you don't want to handle the `PreviewMouseDown` event when the `Image` is clicked you could check the type of the `OriginalSource` of the `RoutedEventArgs` and return immediately from the event handler if it is `Image`:

```
private void listViewItem_MouseDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource is Image)
        return; // do nothing

    MessageBox.Show("ROW CLICKED");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
private void listViewItem_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ROW CLICKED");
    }));
}
```

Comment: I managed to access the `Image` events, but the `ListViewItem` event fires first